# CosmosDB Update c#: Could not determine JSON object type for type System.String[]

Tags: c#, json, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to update a field in CosmosDB to array like below:

"Aliases": [
"John",
"Johnny"
],

Below is my code:

```
           dynamic GuideDoc= new
           {
               id = "00B2845F-F394-5E93-9A26-E70000452562",
               type = "Guide",
               GuideGuid= "00B2845F-F394-5E93-9A26-E70000452562"
           };

           ItemResponse<dynamic> clientGuideResponse1 = await this.container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(GuideGuid, new PartitionKey(PartitionKey));
           dynamic itemBody1 = clientGuideResponse1.Resource;

           String[] AliasesConverted= JSONDecoders.DecodeJSONArray(AliasesValues);
           itemBody1.Aliases= AliasesConverted;

           GuideDoc= itemBody1;

           GuideResponse = await this.container.ReplaceItemAsync<dynamic>(GuideDoc, GuideGuid, new PartitionKey(PartitionKey));
```

The part that stores the data to itemBody1.Aliases is returning an error "Could not determine JSON object type for type System.String[]"

How do I make it save the value to Aliases as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to add new properties while keeping everything else intact is deserializing it into a `Dictionary`. As example:

```cs
var response = await container.ReadItemAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(id, partitionKey);
var item = response.Resource;
item["Aliases"] = new[] { "John", "Johnny" };
await container.ReplaceItemAsync(item, id, partitionKey);
```

The reason it doesn't work is because the deserializer will return the result as `JObject` when you use `dynamic` as type. You can't navigate the `JObject` through the properties as if it were deserialized into a class with properties. The error you describe is a bit different than I would have thought though.